# New job and impossible deadline

Tags: job-search, career-development, new-job

What if after a month of joining, your manager tells you to help release a project which seems next to impossible without the option to extend?

**Background:**

I have joined a new job where the sole developer working on a project and claims that it is almost finished. It's his first job and his programming and coding style is not to industry standards and ready for production.

**Present scenario:**

Neither my colleague nor  management wants me to clean the codebase because it will delay the release date so they are expecting me to continue my work on the crappy codebase.

I was also told that the funding for the project has already finished and they have to wrap up the project as soon as possible.

I really want to do good but this is my first job where management is against a code revision or rewrite. I am considering to look for another position, but want to explore other options before I leave.

Comment: Edited, no need to badmouth your colleague.

Comment: @FrankFYC "not to industry standards" sounds really classy but believe me crappy is reality and I am not happy in saying that, I mean you can't understand even the variable names.

Comment: Does your colleague use SE?

Comment: @FrankFYC don't think so, even if he uses I don't think he will know its him because this kind of story is common :)

Comment: Including the the insults makes you look bad not them... Just FYI.  Showing respect is not about the person you are respecting its about the person you are.

Comment: "What if...?" is not exactly a goal we can address. If you want to leave the job, you're welcome to do so, but we can't make that decision for you. Have you told your manager that you believe the deadline would be impossible to meet? Although issues about the deadline are curiously absent from your question - it just seems like you're insisting on doing a rewrite, which will presumably take a whole lot longer than just doing what you're told. 99.99% of companies would be against a new employee starting off doing a rewrite, especially with a looming deadline.

Comment: This is a really classic tradeoff in working on someone else's code. Unfortunately, many developers will try to rewrite the existing code instead of trying to understand the code base, but it could indeed be a poorly designed software. You can raise your concerns with your management especially on why the software is poorly designed (Will it not scale performance wise? Will it be hard to add new features?) and it's up to management to decide what to do next.

Comment: @Dukeling you are sounding like its ok for 99% of the companies to not do code review? and its ok for 99% companies to let handle a big project by some fresher? I know you are not in the same situation but try to avoid such generic statements which makes little or no sense in some cases. Also, keep in mind that OP must have some experience too its not like if he asking questions here then he needs to be some dumb or something. In your whole comment I smell that you don't believe in the current situation, its ok but don't generalise things.

Comment: @OnetimeOnly I'm not against large-scale rewrites (the opposite, in fact), but they're hard to sell from a business perspective - that's a whole bunch of developer time spent on nothing that makes the company money (the idea is of course that it's beneficial in the long run, but that trade-off is hard to measure beforehand). If you've only been there for a month, it's unreasonable for them to trust you to understand this trade-off (but you may be able to make them understand it). I have no opinion on asking new / newly graduated employees to work on big projects, other than "it happens".

Answer (score 6):

> Neither my colleague nor the management wants me to clean the codebase
>   because it will delay the release date so, they are expecting me to
>   continue my work on the crappy codebase.

Thus, you must continue your work on the crappy codebase, unless you can find some way to clean the codebase and still meet the release date. The way you wrote your question makes that seem unlikely.

> I was also told that the funding for the project has already finished
>   and they have to wrap up the project as soon as possible.

Thus you must strive to wrap up the project as soon as possible. Make sure you and understand what your boss means by "as soon as possible".

> I really want to do good but this is my first job where everyone
>   against it. I really want to run away but I don't want to switch too
>   frequently. What one can do in such situations?

Well, you could run away - but that's not a great solution.

You could give your best estimate for completion and ask for an extension. But it sounds like you have done that and been turned down.

You could ask for more help, if you think that would bring in the completion date. (Sometimes adding people to a project late makes things worse.)

You could ask if features could be trimmed, or the project could be revised in some other way to make the desired release date achievable.

You could ask if the project can simply be canceled. I'm guessing that's not feasible.

When faced with an impossible deadline, I let my boss know that I don't think the target date is achievable. I also let my boss know that I'll do my best with whatever I am given. I update my boss with my estimates as the project goes forward.

I then let my boss make the decision to go ahead with the project, add resources to it, revise it. cancel it, or extend the date.

If the decision is to go ahead without a date extension, then I just do the best I can. In the end, that's all anyone can reasonably expect.

Comment: I am happy to work in the crappy codebase because I have to do less work and be with "flow" but the issue is the project has now my name too and if anything happens then it would be on me too. Also I am on probation period and a failed project may reflect badly on me. I said failed because the way code is written it would sure be failed.

Comment: I understand that everything comes to the understanding of the boss, he is the one who knows the truth and he should see that I am eager to do good but at bad timing. I just scared it shouldn't affect my probation period.

Answer (score 2):

You were assigned to the team, so be a team member.

The best thing you can do is to just take assignments from them, focus on your task, get your tasks completed in a timely and efficient manner, and move on to the next task.

You are the new guy, you are not going to get the pretty project because you have not proven yourself yet.  This project can fail and you can still be successful.  You do that by putting your best effort into getting it done.  Surrender any hopes that the mess that you are working on will be a good project, just work to support the original developer.

At no time should you ever talk down to, or criticize your coworker for mess they have.  It is possible they inherited this mess and are doing what they can to make it work.  And even if not **you are the new guy.**  They do not need you coming in and making the original developer feel bad about what they do or have done.  That is not going to be helpful to the business.

If at some point in the future you are asked about the project and code base, it is fine to offer objective critique of specific choices or problems, but not ok to give generic * his programming and coding style is pathetic and believe me if I say pathetic because I have sufficient experience* - Be specific about the programming choices that were problematic and how the solutions you would have chosen would have solved the problems.

But for now do your best to contribute to the project as a team member following the lead of the existing developer. Sometimes being a good team member means putting being a good programmer on the back burner and just doing what you are told how you are told to do it.

Let them take the credit and blame for driving the project while doing everything in your power to be a great team member.  Prove yourself on this project and hope for a better one next time.  If this is the last time in your career you are handed a crap sandwich and told it needs to taste like prime rib next week, you will be truly blessed.

Comment: "The best thing you can do is to just take assignments from them, focus on your task, get your tasks completed in a timely and efficient manner, and move on to the next task." how? last time when I tried to do my best the only comment I got was "See, you are delaying things no need to refactor". You told me to be a team member but I want to be a good team member I think you didn't read that I have spent great amount of time in learning craft of good programming.

Comment: @OnetimeOnly - Sometimes being a good team member means putting being a good programmer on the back burner and just doing what you are told how you are told to do it.  (I have edited this into the answer btw)  - Just write the code you are told to write to do what you are told to do.  Do not fight the system or hope for a refactor, just do the work and let the project fail on your team leads shoulders.  That is not saying do not offer suggestions, just dont fight to change just because its wrong.

Comment: Sorry if I forgot to tell you, there is no lead. There was this one one guy and I am supposed to be the lead now since I have more experience, sounds funny but true. So, nobody is telling me to write code just there are couple of featured left and that has be completed with my help.

Comment: @OnetimeOnly - He is the lead now... let him be the lead, force him to be the lead, and take his direction.  This is the best course of action for you.  Take that sh@t sandwich and choke it down with a smile on your face and pretend it was wonderful.  No one will remember your part in this failed project in a year.  But being good and positive team member might get you an invite to a better project in the future.

Comment: Yes, you sound right and that I also thought, although it feels a bit embarrassing but the good side is no one knows me here. Lets see what t do after release because I don't think I will be here longer now.

Comment: @OnetimeOnly - It is your choice, but if you run away from a job every time you get put on a crap sandwich project you are going to be running away alot.

Answer (score 0):

Be objective and realistic, take into account the facts of the project and present it in a manner that doesn't burn bridges.

When faced with an immovable object, identify the fact that it is unchanging and offer solutions. If you can't, be direct and say that it is unrealistic.

What can't be changed:

- Funding
- Extension
- Code Revision

This said, my suggestion is to go back to the drawing board and identify which features that needs to be proverbially dumped overboard such that you can salvage what's remaining to meet the deadline. With the idea that it is better to have well polished code for some features than a bug-ridden code that covers all the requested features. Once it is wrapped with a bow tie, state how with more funding, you can tackle the missing features.

Your colleague, although inexperienced, is not performing maliciously. This is his/her first job and was assigned to a one-man dev team without a mentor. Sounds like you can now fill that role. If you move forward riding him/her for their mistakes, you are now in the wrong. You are aware of the reason why for the poor quality, yet you choose to act with malice. This is an opportunity to grow for the both of you, you as a leader, and he/she as a better programmer.

Comment: I tried that after couple of weeks of joining but the issue is the my colleague is a fresher and its very hard to persuade him, sometimes I fail to communicate with him because he has little or no knowledge. He always says that there is nothing wrong we can do this or that which doesn't make sense.

Comment: You don't have to persuade him. You have to persuade the project manager. "I conferred with X about issues A, B, and C. X replied, a, b, and c. I would disagree based on D, E, and F. I am bringing this to you for your decision." Once a decision has been made, then it's out of your hands.

Comment: Today I was thinking to take the printouts of the codes before and after refactoring and show him the drastic change in readability and complexity but the manager's comment regarding funding is holding me back.

Comment: Funding is outside of your control. You present your professional opinion and leave the decision making to the manager. If your manager decides against what you recommend, don't take it personally, do what you can with what you've been given. This project will not be the end of the world.

Answer (score -2):

Don't worry about it, it's government. Failed projects are par for the course. Many departments are all about getting funding and all their resources go to that, the actual project is less important or they wouldn't have had your predecessor on it in the first place.

They're already focused on the next source of funding.

So just do what you can.